# How can i follow user with Instagram api?

Tags: api, instagram, instagram-api

```
function loadEmUp() 
    {
          $(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "jsonp",
                cache: false,
                url: 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/351508/relationship?action=follow&access_token=accesstoken',
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                }
            });
        });
    }

    $(document).ready(function () {
        loadEmUp(myApiLink);
    });
```

But I can't follow, I always get

> {"meta":{"code":200},"data":{"outgoing_status":"none","target_user_is_private":false,"incoming_status":"none"}}

How can I follow the user?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited the title of your question to be more concise. I also indented your code sample by 4 spaces so that it renders properly - please see the editing help for more information on formatting. Last, I fixed some general formatting so that the question is more readable. Please edit your question to add any details necessary to identify the specific problem. Good luck!

Comment: is there anybody to help ?

Comment: Hi you got solution?